# MongoDB sortByCount operator

Tags: mongodb

Trying to use a `$count` or `$sortByCount` function in MongoDB to group and count employees by their age brackets - how many having a salary between 0 and 40000, how many - between 40001 and 45000 etc.
Not getting what I want. Tried that -

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match:{$and:[{salary:{$gte:0}},{salary{$lt:40000}}]}},{$sortByCount:"$salary"}])
```

but instead of grouping these two into 1 salary bracket and counting as 2, it counts them individually.

```
{ "_id" : 35554.54, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 31500.66, "count" : 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for the [$bucket](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/?searchProperty=current&query=sortbycount#bucket-aggregation) stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$bucket: {
          groupBy: "$salary",
          boundaries: [0, 40000, 45000, 50000, 55000],
    }}
])
```

This will give you results like

```
{ "_id" : 45000, "count" : 43 }
{ "_id" : 40000, "count" : 49 }
{ "_id" : 50000, "count" : 492 }
```

If you would rather have the group boundaries computed dynamically, you could use `$addFields` with some arithmetic operators, and then `$group`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$addFields:{ 
         salaryBucket:{$multiply:[{$round:[{$divide:["$salary",5000]},0]},5000]}
    }},
    {$group: {
          _id:"$salaryBucket",
          count:{$sum:1}
    }}
])
```

Comment: check here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/91Mmef3JgGl